# Google chrome extension for screen capture and edit them

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to create a chrome extension like Zephyre capture for jira.But I am stuck how to write code for capture screenshot and edit that screenshot.Please help..

Comment: This is way too broad of a question. You have to show what you've tried and what's not working

Comment: I only want when we click on icon of extension then it capture screenshot of visible part and open that screenshot on new tab for further editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several samples online that can actually help you with your 'screenshot extension' endeavor. This [orbitbot github repo](https://github.com/orbitbot/chrome-extensions-examples/tree/master/screenshot) has plenty of samples including a screenshot demo. Another one is [Amindav's sample](https://github.com/Aminadav/screenshot-extension/blob/master/chrome-extensions/js/screenshot.js).

Answer (score 0):

you get captured screenshot data in base-XX format suing this API
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture

you can edit the email using base-XX